# Creating Views based on html source

Tags: views, blocks, javascript

Is it possible to create a view from third-party source that includes html, js and css?

Example: http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/shinetime/

I want to create a view of the example shown in the link and display it as a block on my site.
Is there an automated process for doing this or I would have to do it manually? If manually then how? Thank you

Comment: No it is not possible like you says. But there is a way.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is display that in/on your website, include it in an iframe, eg, create a block that just has:

```
<iframe src="http://www.addyosmani.com/resources/shinetime/"></iframe>
```

in it.

Now, if you are wanting to create a View, eg http://drupal.org/project/views, then you need to give some more specifics of what you are wanting to do.

Comment: the iframe is a good idea however it doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 0):

If i didn't get you wrong, you want to have this kind of block with your fields with the help of views.
There are no automated process for this.

You got to copy or download the source of this stuff (the markup, js, css). In my humble opinion the easiest way to do this with views is just having your needed fields (title, images) and then overriding the html output of these fields to fit your css and js selectors. Also you can set classes and markup in the format and fields settings in the view created.

There is also different method: hide all of your fields and leave the lowest one. Check to override the output of it and put the markup you need, replacing titles and images, description and other with your fields which would be listed below in the patterns examples.

Answer (score -2):

In my opinion, you can create a basic page and code the PHP + HTML code. (You must enable PHP filter in module page)

For the php code, you create a SQL statement to get the data that you want, for example, [db_query in Drupal](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_query/7)

Comment: Just an FYI, the PHP filter is akin to the devil.